# stop building the project in eclipse or using maven if no of error/warnings increases to a certain limit?

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, maven, jshint

I am using JsHint tool (Static Analysis warning tool)as eclipse plug-in in my project that will give the javascript warnings in my project files.
Now I need that eclipse stop building project when number of warnings given by JsHint increases beyond certain limit.
Is there any solution for the same

Thanks
Anil

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the amount of errors reported per file by setting the option [maxerr](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#maxerr), but you can't stop the builder. If you could, this would lead to the impression that some files in a project are clean even though they are not (because the just haven't been checked).

If you still think that you need this feature, feel free to open a new [issue](https://github.com/eclipsesource/jshint-eclipse/issues) and explain your problem there.